# In Google Website Optimizer, can I use a page in 2 tests simultaneously?

Tags: google-website-optimizer, ab-testing

Best explained via example...I want:

One A/B test to alternate between  PageA and PageB.

A second A/B test then alternates between PageC and PageB.

In other words, I want PageB to be and active option in 2 tests at the same time.
My question is: Will the test results make sense? I'm concerned that if 100 visitors go through the first test, and 100 visitors go throug h the second test, then the test results report will look like this:
    First A/B test:    PageA    20/50   (conversions / visits)
                       PageB    60/100

```
Second A/B test:   PageA    40/50   (conversions / visits)
                   PageB    60/100
```

(see, if 15 of the 50 visitors from the first test PageB visitors converted, and 45 of the second test's PageB visitors converted, then PageB should lose both tests! But the numbers together make it look like it is winning.

Or is GWO smart enough to know that "This page view is a result of a Test1 redirect, so only count the results for that test."

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "switches".

GWO uses two sections - control script and tracking script.  The control script goes on any page where you want something to happen, and the tracking script goes on the destination / conversion page only.  A single page can be the destination / conversion page for many tests without problem.

If you're hoping to control two tests on one page you'll have to provide more detail on what you are doing.  Are you using javascript to do a redirect in a multivariate test, or are you running A/B tests?